# Software metric tool for Python

Tags: python

I want a tool which can compute source code metrics such as lines of code, number of packages, classes, functions, cyclomatic complexity number, depth of inheritance tree etc. for my Python Code.
I have tried pylint, but it didn't offer much metrics.
pynocle seemed interesting but I dont know how to use it.

Can anyone give me some suggestions ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The pynocle Google Code page has some example output, and the code used to generate them is in their source repo: http://code.google.com/p/pynocle/source/browse/test_init.py

Comment: Can you suggest some other tool ?

Answer (score 1):

[PyGenie](http://traceback.org/2008/03/31/measuring-cyclomatic-complexity-of-python-code/) can do cyclomatic complexity. I have used it once before and it used to be Python-3 incompatible... haven't used it afterward. Maybe give it a shot?

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/).

Answer (score 0):

try `radon`, It calculate Cyclomatic Complexity, Maintainability Index and Raw metrics like LOC, SLOC and...